# How can I style a part of a single character with overlays using a dynamic width?

Tags: html, css, overlay

### Question

Can I style just a part of a single character?

### Meaning

CSS attributes cannot be assigned to parts of characters. But if you want to style only a certain section of a character, there is no standardized way to do that.

### Example

Is it possible to style an "X" which is half-way red and then black?

[image: Expected result]

### Not working code

```
<div class="content"> 
    X
</div>
```

```css
.content {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: black;
}

.content:after {
    content: 'X';
    color: red;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**Demo on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tYPqb/1/)

### Purpose

My intention is styling the Font Awesome [**`icon-star`**](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#icon/icon-star) symbol. If I have an overlay with dynamic width, shouldn't it be possible to create an exact visualization of scores?

Comment: I've seen something similar at the LGM shown by Ricardo Lafuente and Ana Carvalho: [colorfont.js](http://manufacturaindependente.com/colorfont/)

Comment: I asked a similar question recently and it received a lot more attention. You can find it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While playing around with a demo fiddle, i figured it out myself and wanted to share my solution. It's quite simple.

### First things first: [**The DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v5xzJ/1/)

To partly style a single character, you need extra markup for your content. Basically, you need to duplicate it:

```
<​div class="content"> 
    <span class="overlay">X</span>
    X
</div>
```

Using pseudo-elements like :after or :before would be nicer, but i didn't found a way to do that.

The overlay needs to be positioned absolutely to the content element:

```
​.content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: black;
}

​.overlay {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}​
```

Do not forget `overflow: hidden;` in order to cut off the remaing part of the "X".

You can use any width instead of `50%` which makes this approach very flexible. You can even use a custom height, other CSS attributes or a combination of multiple attributes.

### **[Extended DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v5xzJ/2/)**

Comment: How can I do it but with an image that has transparent backround?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Please create a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Great work on your solution. I’ve got a version that uses `:after` (instead of duplicating the content in the HTML) working in Chrome 19.

- http://jsfiddle.net/v5xzJ/4/

Basically:

1. Set `position:relative` on `.content`
2. Position `:after` absolutely
3. Set `:after` to `overflow:hidden`
4. Adjust the width, height, text-indent and line-height of `:after` to hide bits of it.

I’m not sure if it’ll work well cross-browser though — the `em` values will probably work out a bit differently. (Obviously it definitely won’t work in IE 7 or below.)

In addition, you end up having to duplicate the content in your CSS file instead of the HTML, which might not be optimal depending on the situation.

Comment: that's a good solution too! i like the clean markup. now people can choose weather they want to duplicate their content in html or css