# Can I have different color on half of text using css or js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have 2 different colors on text on different halves i.e. upper half of text of different color and other half of other.
Like in this image..

[image]

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character

Comment: in the css that is linked from the answer given by the duplicate, for the element ".halfStyle.hs-base:before" change "width: 50%;" to "height: 50%;"

Comment: Thanks. This worked so well:

.halfed {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 300px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative; /* To help hold the content value within */
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #9A2617;
}

.halfed:before   {
  width: 100%; /* How much we'd like to show */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide what goes beyond our dimension */  
  content: 'Institute'; /* Halfed character */
  height: 55%;
  position: absolute;
  color: #541D85;
}