# How to invert colors horizontally halfway through a word using CSS

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how to invert the colors horizontally in the middle of a word (or character) like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmkYg.png).

I tried tweaking the solutions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981763/invert-css-font-color-depending-on-background-color) that details how to do it when it's spliced vertically, but I couldn't get it to work. I know it can be done using only HTML and CSS, but I have no idea where to begin.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**: This is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character), because I'm looking to do a horizontal split, not a vertical one (I do see the answer that shows a horizontal split, but the text looks funny — it looks like different colored versions of the characters were overlapped maybe?). I did try looking on codepen, but I was only finding solutions for vertical splits.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: Have you looked on codepen.io ? Also, how about asking on graphic design or calligraphy forum what that effect is called? Then you can search better?