# How to paint half of a letter or text in HTML(CSS)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have : `<p>A</p>`

Is there any way in html or css or Javascript which I am able to paint half of "A" white and the other black or any other color.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Comment: Need some sample design

Comment: @Robbie That is for `background` not `color` which is what is used for font color.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak How is a background gradient relevant to the OPs issue? Also, please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: @j08691 yea, I was totally baffled as to how that got upvotes

Comment: Try SVG this is the best solution to solve it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/robbiemilejczak/xwh9ey4y/ it is

Comment: The answer is pretty much explained in [Is it possible to apply CSS to half of a character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character?rq=1). Basically it's possible but pretty hard.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak while your solution works, you didn't address the most important point which is the background-clip. Don't just post links and assume everything is understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it with gradients as Robbie suggested. There is only one down side of this. You won't be able to use text-shadow property *(except with another hack - make duplicate of text and give it the shadow property)*

**Edited on request...**

```
p {
  font-size: 12px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000, #DDD);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Source code can be found here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/