# (CSS) inherit RGB values in linear-gradient possible?

Tags: css, colors, opacity, linear-gradients

I am using a rating system that used to display *Font Awesome* star (and half star) icons, which I recently switched to headphone icons. Font awesome provides a half-star icon but doesn't provide a half-headphone icon. So I had to use CSS to only display half an icon (full-opacity) and the other half with less opacity. This is how I did it:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(206, 55, 72) 50%, rgba(206, 55, 72, 0.28) 50%);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Example (see the red icons below for a rating of 4.5 headphones): 
[image]

---

Problem is, I also use this same rating in other places, where the font color is different. But because I'm defining a specific RGB value, it's using the same color across the entire site for my half-headphone.

Check it out:

[image]

---

Can I "inherit" the color while using linear-gradient and only affect the opacity of the icon?

Such as:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, inherit 50%, rgba(inherit, 0.28) 50%);
```

Or is there another approach to this?

Thank you.

Comment: You *could* do it with CSS custom properties (variables) but you'd need three of them and it's get messy.

Comment: `CurrentColor` could work for the first stop but not the second.

Comment: ..but this might be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character/23569891#23569891

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for the link, I saw that earlier but I was hoping for another option as that plugin looks like overkill for such a basic need. But the plugin does look awesome... I'll have to check that out in the meantime. Thanks brother.

Comment: i agree with @Paulie_D, the best way here is CSS variabes

Comment: Thanks guys, i'll look into that.