# Set 2 color for an icon font

Tags: css, icons

I'm using IcoMoon font icons. I would like to display a star icon 80% blue and 20% white like the image below. How would I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I usually use when i want to do a rating bar. [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/4qqspqxh/)

```
<div class="ratings">
    <div class="empty-stars"></div>
    <div class="full-stars" style="width:85%"></div>
</div>
```

You just place two icons on top of each other and limit the width of the colored ones.