# How can I make each odd letter in my header h1 to have an orange color

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit confused as to how I can go about this. 
I tried: 
    `h1:nth-child(odd) { color: orange; }`
but that didn't work.

Here's my html:

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <header>
      <h1> Simple & Responsive Flexbox Website! </h1>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: there is no way to do this wih selector ... you need some color trick, like gradient, etc

Comment: @TemaniAfif what do you mean?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character to have some ideas .. and there is no selector for letters,

Comment: I don't want half a letter to be coloured, I want each odd letter to be fully coloured. If that makes sense? @TemaniAfif

Comment: i gave hint :) i know what you want .. you need to chekc this question to get some ways on how to color text partially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var myColors = ["red", "green"];
$('.text-content').find('h1').each(function(){
  var $el = $(this),
    text = $el.text(),
    len = text.length,
    coLen = myColors.length,
    newCont = '';
  for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
    newCont += '<span style="color:'+ myColors[i%coLen] +'">'+ text.charAt(i) +'</span>';
  }
  $el.html(newCont);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="text-content">
    <h1>Simple & Responsive Flexbox Website!</h1>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

See below. You can used http://letteringjs.com/ if you like to wrap characters in `span` tags.

```css
h1>span {
color: blue;
}
h1>span:nth-child(odd) {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>S</span>
  <span>i</span>
  <span>m</span>
  <span>p</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>e</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap each letter in individual spans (if you wanted to only use HTML), then target the `:odd` spans.

`<style> h1 span:odd { color: orange; } </style>`

`<h1>`

`<span>S</span>`

`<span>i</span>`

`<span>m</span>`

`<span>p</span>`

`<span>l</span>`

`<span>e</span>`

`</h1>`

Using javascript might open up some other opportunities to make this more efficient, or simpler to write, but will likely still use the span method to delegate the color property to individual characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea that will only work with monospace font:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, orange 0, orange 1ch, black 1ch, black 2ch);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1> Simple & Responsive Flexbox Website!</h1>
```