# How to color fill a unicode (star: \u2605) character only half way in css/html?

Tags: html, css

How to take something like a star unicode `\u2605` which is a star in html/css and only fill it half way instead of full.

Here is code:

```
<div class="starHalfFill">
 \u2605
</div>
```

My styles look like this thus far:

```
.starHalfFill {
  color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is colored by color and not background color we will have to do a little more work to get this filled halfway. Normally to fill a div half way you would do something like:

```
.starHalfFill {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, orange 50%, grey 50%);
}
```

but since this is a text based color we will have to target that.

```
     .star.star--non-filled {
        background: linear-gradient(to right, orange 50%, grey 50%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      }
```

Those properties will target the text inside the div and also make the fill color transparent allowing the effect to work.

Comment: so exactly like this most popular question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character ?

Comment: @TaylorAustin Can you include a fiddle? This doesn't seem to work. https://jsfiddle.net/nph/3wvq7ew6/1/

Comment: Future question seekers; from MDN: `-webkit-text-fill-color` **This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web:**

Comment: I didn't see that at all ill duplicate.