# Half font awesome heart rating css

Tags: html, css

I'm generating a rating system using font-awesome fa-heart class. It is working fine by colouring the full heart, but I'm in trouble when trying to fill it in red only the first half of the heart.
I have been searching but always are stars and not a half-heart, always full heart and not from font-awesome.

Font awesome version used 4.0.3 and cannot be changed...

Any trick to do that?

```css
.full {
  color:red;
}
.half {

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="rating-love ">
     <span class="fa fa-heart full"></span>
     <span class="fa fa-heart full"></span>
     <span class="fa fa-heart full"></span>
     <span class="fa fa-heart full"></span>
     <span class="fa fa-heart half"></span>  
     <a href="#reviews"><span>23 Review(s)</span></a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: FA is an icon font, so each icon is a single glyph. As far as I'm aware there's no way in HTML/CSS/JS to have a single glyph have different colours. You could do something like use a paler colour for a "partial" heart.

Comment: Not dupe, but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is another idea where you can easily have any kind of rating by simply adjusting a CSS variable:

```css
.rating-love {
  display: inline-grid!important;
}

.rating-love:before,
.rating-love:after {
  content: "\f004  \f004  \f004  \f004  \f004";
  grid-area: 1/1;
}

.rating-love:after {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: var(--w);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="rating-love fa" style="--w: 50%;"></div>

<br>

<div class="rating-love fa" style="--w: 30%;"></div>

<br>

<div class="rating-love fa" style="--w: 80%;"></div>
```

Comment: Semantically though, giving all the hearts the `full` class isn't really the best thing to do.

Comment: This is an interesting take on the problem; only problem is using a fixed width in the `.rate` span because FA icons are text and there is no actual fixed width.

Comment: @JamesDouglas no need to use fixed width :) .. you can use % also if you remove the other text and make it outside. In this case 100% width will be the width of the 5 stars whataver the font-size is

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif! Goog approach but dificult to adjust the width when generating dinamically.

Comment: @Albeis check again it's updating with % now ;)

Comment: finally I have used your aproach :)

Comment: mannn you saved me soo much time this is an excellent solution thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using text Clip & Background Gradient, I hope this trick will work for you too. 
I just made a gradient with 2 colors and divided them with clip its looking fine. You can make half of the heart white if you want just by changing the hexcode in css.

```
.fa-heart.half:before {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg,#000 0%, #000 50%,#FF0000 50%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```css
.full {
  color:red;
}
.half {

}
.fa-heart.half:before {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg,#000 0%, #000 50%,#FF0000 50%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="rating-love ">
     <span class="fa fa-heart full"></span>
     <span class="fa fa-heart full"></span>
     <span class="fa fa-heart full"></span>
     <span class="fa fa-heart full"></span>
     <span class="fa fa-heart half"></span>  
     <a href="#reviews"><span>23 Review(s)</span></a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Nice solution! Unfortunately it probably isn't very cross-browser compatible, but still a really good idea.

Comment: `text-stroke` Is not supported in IE. https://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke

Comment: @JamesDouglas Yes Unfortunately IE is not supporting Text-stroke, :(

Comment: That’s the approach I was looking for. Its a pity that it is not working on IE but anyway, thanks!

Comment: I will look for options if somehow this solution is possible in IE, will update you here.

Answer (score 3):

Without using JavaScript you'd cut the width of the span to half, hiding the overflow.

```css
.full {
  color: red;
  vertical-align:text-bottom;
}

.half {
  color: red;
  width: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align:text-bottom;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="rating-love ">
  <span class="fa fa-heart full"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-heart full"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-heart full"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-heart full"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-heart half"></span>
  <a href="#reviews"><span>23 Review(s)</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but there is some margin above the last heart which ruins the effect...

Comment: @JamesDouglas Incorrect, the last heart span has no margin other than the right one which I gave it. So, nothing ruined.

Comment: I see margin on my computer. I am using Firefox on OSX. [Here is a screenshot of what I see.](https://s8.postimg.cc/vvaz6kgp1/Screen_Shot_2018-08-07_at_17.18.09.png)

Comment: @JamesDouglas Looks like the vertical align instead.

Comment: It can be solved by adding `vertical-align:text-bottom;` to the `.full` spans as well; I have taken the liberty to edit your answer to include it.