# How to color a word in 2 colors?

Tags: html, css

How do I color the word with black and purple, like in the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y98V.png)

```
<h3 id="logo"> tripbit</h3>

#logo {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 47.0943px;
    line-height: 53px;
    letter-spacing: -0.05em;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23569898/8620333

Answer (score 0):

There are many options:

1. Applying a griadient to the text.
2. Overlaying the same text on :: before with a different color and an equivalent z-index.
3. You can add `<span>` to each letter and give the appropriate color in css.